# Haskell use Data from POST REQUEST

Tags: http, haskell, post, web-crawler, http-conduit

I want to get the body of [geocodeip.com](http://geocodeip.com/) with a POST request (the ip in the textbox).

Here my code:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.C.String

import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
getGPS :: String -> IO ()
getGPS ip = do
  initReq <- parseUrl "http://www.geocodeip.com/"
  let req = (flip urlEncodedBody) initReq $ [("IP", C8.pack ip)]
  let res = withManager $ httpLbs req
  tags <- fmap parseTags ( (responseBody res))
  print tags

--foreign export ccall getGPS :: CString -> IO ()
```

So far it is working if i "finish" he function with `L.putStr $ responseBody res` ... but how can I get the `tags` out of this?

Compile-Error:

```
    Couldn't match type ‘Response L.ByteString’ with ‘L.ByteString’
    Expected type: Response L.ByteString
      Actual type: Response (Response L.ByteString)
    In the first argument of ‘responseBody’, namely ‘res’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘responseBody res’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How to solve this type-error?

Comment: try `let res = withManager $ httpLbs req` instead of `res <- withManager $ httpLbs req`.

Comment: I have edited my post. still an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are confused by do-notation and monadic/non-monadic code.
Here is how I would write it.

```
getGPS :: String -> IO ()
getGPS ip = do
  initReq <- parseUrl "http://www.geocodeip.com/"
  let req = urlEncodedBody [("IP", C8.pack ip)] initReq
  res <- withManager $ httpLbs req
  let tags = parseTags (responseBody res)
  print tags
```

Comment: thanks! but can you tell me please where the difference between `let .. = ..` and `.. <- ..` is?

Comment: `let` is just name binding whereas `<-` is part of the do notation. You can read more here : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation